# Python crashes when accessing pointer in struct returned from ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I am trying to access a tree returned by this function in Python:

```
TokenTreeNode* generateTokenTree(const wchar_t** tokens, const unsigned int tokenCount, const BlockToken* blockTokens, const unsigned int blockTokenCount);
```

The definition of TokenTreeNode:

```
typedef struct tree_node_struct {
    wchar_t* token;
    size_t childCount;
    struct tree_node_struct* parent;
    struct tree_node_struct** children;
} TokenTreeNode;
```

The definition of BlockToken:

```
typedef struct {
    const wchar_t* begin;
    const wchar_t* end;
} BlockToken;
```

And here is the code of the corresponding ctypes python interface:

```
import ctypes
from typing import List

class CBlockToken(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('begin', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('end',   ctypes.c_wchar_p)]

class CTokenTreeNode(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('token',      ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('childCount', ctypes.c_size_t),
                ('parent',     ctypes.POINTER('CTokenTreeNode')),
                ('children',   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER('CTokenTreeNode')))]

def generate_token_tree(tokens: List[str], blockTokens: List[CBlockToken]) -> CTokenTreeNode:
    nativelib = ctypes.WinDLL(source_path + '\\nativelib\\x64\\Release\\nativelib.dll')

    generateTokenTree = nativelib.generateTokenTree
    generateTokenTree.argtype = [
        ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ctypes.c_uint,
        ctypes.POINTER(CBlockToken),
        ctypes.c_uint
    ]
    generateTokenTree.restype = ctypes.POINTER(CTokenTreeNode)

    c_arg_tokens             = (ctypes.c_wchar_p * len(tokens))(*tokens)
    c_arg_token_count        = len(tokens)
    c_arg_block_tokens       = (CBlockToken * len(blockTokens))(*blockTokens)
    c_arg_block_tokens_count = len(blockTokens)
    
    root_node = generateTokenTree(c_arg_tokens,
                                  c_arg_token_count,
                                  c_arg_block_tokens,
                                  c_arg_block_tokens_count)

    return root_node.contents
```

When I try to access the children of the returned root node python crashes.

```
>>> test_tokens  = ['var', 'test', '=', '"', 'string', '"']
>>> block_tokens = [parser.CBlockToken('"', '"')]
>>> root_node = parser.generate_token_tree(test_tokens, block_tokens)
>>> root_node.childCount
4
>>> root_node.children[0].contents

python crashes
```

If I access the generated tree in C++, everything works as expected. To me the problem seems to be that python is for some reason not allowed to access memory that was allocated by the external library. However, I have no idea how I could fix or even debug this issue.

EDIT: changed the type of TreeTokenNode.childCount as suggested by @MilesBudnek

EDIT 2:
Here is the memory layout of the tree right at the end of generateTokenTreeNode() according to the debugger:

```
-       rootNode->children,10   0x000001e3c7454250 {0x000001e3c74544f0 {token=0x000001e3c7456b30 L"var" childCount=0 parent=0x000001e3c7454a90 {...} ...}, ...} tree_node_struct *[10]
+       [0] 0x000001e3c74544f0 {token=0x000001e3c7456b30 L"var" childCount=0 parent=0x000001e3c7454a90 {token=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> ...} ...}   tree_node_struct *
+       [1] 0x000001e3c74547f0 {token=0x000001e3c74565e0 L"test" childCount=0 parent=0x000001e3c7454a90 {token=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> ...} ...}  tree_node_struct *
+       [2] 0x000001e3c7454130 {token=0x000001e3c537d0e0 L"=" childCount=0 parent=0x000001e3c7454a90 {token=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> ...} ...} tree_node_struct *
-       [3] 0x000001e3c7454d30 {token=0x000001e3c7456360 L"\"\"" childCount=1 parent=0x000001e3c7454a90 {token=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> ...} ...}  tree_node_struct *
    -       children    0x000001e3c74569f0 {0x000001e3c7454df0 {token=0x000001e3c74567c0 L"string" childCount=0 parent=0x000001e3c7454d30 {...} ...}}   tree_node_struct * *
    -           0x000001e3c7454df0 {token=0x000001e3c74567c0 L"string" childCount=0 parent=0x000001e3c7454d30 {token=...} ...}  tree_node_struct *
        +       token   0x000001e3c74567c0 L"string"    wchar_t *
        childCount  0   unsigned __int64
        +       parent  0x000001e3c7454d30 {token=0x000001e3c7456360 L"\"\"" childCount=1 parent=0x000001e3c7454a90 {token=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> ...} ...}  tree_node_struct *
        +       children    0x0000000000000000 {???}    tree_node_struct * *
```

Here the function was called from python code and we can see that the memory layout is correct before the data sructure is accessed by python. If we try to read a child of the root node, an access violation occurs.

Comment: `CTokenTreeNode`'s `childCount` field should probably be `ctypes.c_size_t`, not `c_uint`.  `unsigned int` is generally 4 bytes, while `size_t` is often 8 bytes.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I changed that, unfortunately it did not make any difference.

Comment: One error is *generateTokenTree.argtype**s***. Check [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011). Also `('parent',     ctypes.POINTER('CTokenTreeNode')),` NO QUOTES around *CTokenTreeNode* !